# Using Cognito Form Creator to create Order Forms with Multiple Available Options

Tags: cognito-forms

Using the Cognito Form creator there does not seem to be a very straightford way of creating an Order  form with multiple available items for possible selection; where each available items has different possible options such as sizes and colors. Here is an example of my order form that have created using JotForm: https://form.jotform.com/omillbro/CalAfrica_Online_OrderForm . I would like to create this same form using Cognito including the images. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I work on the support team for Cognito Forms.

Your JotForm link gives me a 404 error, so I couldn't see the specific form you are trying to replicate.  However, you should be able to do exactly that kind of multiple option order entry with a [repeating section](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections).

There's a good example of implementing the kind of order form you are talking about here: [Implementing Cascading Options](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/how-to-implement-cascading-choices-in-cognito-forms).